# Column comparison in Django queries

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a following model:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    mileage_limit = models.IntegerField()
    mileage = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to select all cars where mileage is less than mileage_limit, so in SQL it would be something like:

```
select * from car where mileage < mileage_limit;
```

Using Q object in Django, I know I can compare columns with any value/object, e.g. if I wanted to get cars that have mileage say less than 100,000 it would be something like:

```
cars = Car.objects.filter(Q(mileage__lt=100000))
```

Instead of a fixed value I would like to use the column name (in my case it is mileage_limit). So I would like to be able to do something like:

```
cars = Car.objects.filter(Q(mileage__lt=mileage_limit))
```

However this results in an error, since it is expecting a value/object, not a column name. Is there a way to compare two columns using Q object? I feel like it would be a very commonly used feature and there should be an easy way to do this, however couldn't find anything about it in the documentation.

*Note: this is a simplified example, for which the use of Q object might seem to be unnecessary. However the real model has many more columns, and the real query is more complex, that's why I am using Q. Here in this question I just wanted to figure out specifically how to compare columns using Q.*

**EDIT**

Apparently after release of Django 1.1 it would be possible to do the following:

```
cars = Car.objects.filter(mileage__lt=F('mileage_limit'))
```

Still not sure if F is supposed to work together with Q like this:

```
cars = Car.objects.filter(Q(mileage__lt=F('mileage_limit')))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do this right now without custom SQL.  The django devs are working on an F() function that would make it possible: [#7210 - F() syntax, design feedback required.](http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/c8cff7e5e16c692a#)

Comment: I am looking at ticket 7210 http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7210 seams like this issue has been already addressed. Anyone knows when it is going to be released? Is it part of 1.1 release?

Comment: It should be part of Django 1.1, which is scheduled for a March release.  It will probably go into SVN trunk quite a bit sooner, though, so you could use it from there.

Comment: And it's now in Django SVN trunk, so you can get it if you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Since I had to look this up based on the accepted answer, I wanted to quickly mention that the `F()` expression has indeed been released and is available for being used in queries.

This is what the [Django documentation on `F()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) says about it:

> An F() object represents the value of a model field, transformed value of a model field, or annotated column. It makes it possible to refer to model field values and perform database operations using them without actually having to pull them out of the database into Python memory.
>
> Instead, Django uses the F() object to generate an SQL expression that describes the required operation at the database level.

The [reference for making queries using `F()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters) also gives useful examples.