# How to compare value of 2 fields in Django QuerySet?

Tags: python, django, model

I have a django model like this:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    batting = models.IntegerField()
    bowling = models.IntegerField()
```

What would be the Django QuerySet equivalent of the following SQL?

```
SELECT * FROM player WHERE batting > bowling;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Column comparison in Django queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433294/column-comparison-in-django-queries)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In django 1.1 you can do the following:

```
players = Player.objects.filter(batting__gt=F('bowling'))
```

See the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433294/column-comparison-in-django-queries) for details